# Searching Tables from VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

As much as I hate asking without having a good start I am stuck on something very simple I think.

I have a table with only 3 fields. I want to be able to search them using a InputBox which I call from VBA. My problem is I do not know how to actually search the fields. I have my InputBox but once I have the number/text saved as a variable I do not have a clue how to call it to search through the table and display the results. I apologize if this question has been answered but I couldn't find anything that helped me before posting this.

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter

Comment: Are you using a form with an InputBox I assume?  Because you can use a `select` statement and use the variable in the `where` parameter.  Then use your recorset and `.MoveNext` to move through each record or use a listbox to show it all with `.RowSource = sql_statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim DB as Database
Dim Rec as Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDB
Set Rec = DB.OpenRecordset ("Select * from MyTable where MyField LIKE '*" & Me.MyTextbox & "*'")
```

I suppose you can have a datasheet or continuous form that displays the results of Rec?  You may need to tweak that a bit; for instance you may need to use the CHR value of a double quote instead of using the single quote in the LIKE statement.  I apologize for not supplying a more complete answer, it's a busy day!  :o)

Comment: @Chuck Also, if you're not familiar with recordsets, once you apply the code above, you can then get the individual field values from it with `msgbox Rec.Fields("MyFieldName")` or `msgbox Rec.Fields(i)` (where i is the column number).